# Accept inbound Bluetooth pairing request programmatically on an RPi3 running windows IoT

Tags: bluetooth, raspberry-pi3, windows-10-iot-core

I am using an RPi3 to control a machine which will be able to communicate with android and other bluetooth devices. I used the Rfcomm Bluetooth chat example to  establish bluetooth communication. The issue that I am facing right now is that my android app cannot connect to windows app until the two devices pair and I need to go on the windows device portal to accept the pairing request for the RPi. Is there a way to automate this programmatically so that the windows app can accept all inbound pairing requests?

Answer (score 0):

You could programmatically pair/unpair request on RPi3 running with windows IoT.  Please refer to scenarios 8 and 9 in this uwp sample: https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/DeviceEnumerationAndPairing.

It seems that windows 10/ Windows 10 IoT Core does not support ***DevicePairingKinds.None***.I have tested to pair with parameter as DevicePairingKinds.None,it is failed. You can set as DevicePairingKinds.ConfirmOnly to work around.

```
deviceInfoDisp.DeviceInformation.Pairing.Custom.PairAsync(DevicePairingKinds.ConfirmOnly);
```

Comment: I looked at this example. It allows you to pair/unpair with a device through the app. But it does not monitor incoming pairing requests. I want to programmatically monitor incoming pairing requests and accept them all.